# Password protect page using Django but no user registration

Tags: django

I am looking to implement simple password protection for one of my Django Views. Ideally, when users visit the page, they will see a form where they can enter the password (same password for everyone, no user accounts) and if it's correct they will be forwarded to the view with semi-sensitive information. The password will be given out in person at club meetings and through email.

I don't want to implement users accounts and I would like the password to be easily changeable from the Django admin panel. Actual security strength/encryption is pretty low priority as it is just a list of club member's phone numbers I am hoping to hide.

I have looked into HTTP Auth but I think that would work because the password couldn't be changed from the Django administration page.

What is the easiest way to implement this type of system?

Comment: After looking around more, I think 'django-lockdown' will do what I need. However, I'm a little confused about what I need to do to get the lockdown decorator working in views.py. I am getting the error "name 'lockdown' is not defined'

Also, with lockdown, is there a way I can change LOCKDOWN_PASSWORDS from the django administration panel?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I need the same thing. No accounts, just an administrative password that one or more people can know. (That's the difference in my requirements, it's an administrative page) It's pretty trivial to roll this myself but I would love to use the framework instead.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something similar to this, will suffice your need:
 https://www.djangopackages.com/packages/p/django-registration-invitationcode-backend/

You can also have a look at https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/authentication/, other packages such as lazy signup, and django-privatebeta, are close to your requirements.