# how to create a password protected post page

Tags: python, django, django-views

So I have develop a web site by django, everything works fine now. But I want to make one post that are protected by password which means you need to put in password to view the content of post. I search the internet and really didn't found a way to do that, some suggested hard code in post with password. I want more dynamic where you can edit in you admin post page with password protect option. similar to question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213704/password-protect-page-using-django-but-no-user-registration).

Answer (score 0):

```
def password_protected_post(request):
    if request.mothod == 'POST':
        form = passwordform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            if password == my_password:
                 return 'the content you want to show'
    else:
       ....'show the passwordform'
```